# How to pass collection_select value with link_to_remote in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to pass collection_select drop down list value with link_to_remote.

```
<%= collection_select("event", "trainer_id", @trainers , :id, :name, {:prompt => true}) %>
<%= link_to_remote 'Show calendar', :url => {:controller => 'calendar', :action => 'trainer_view'} %>
```

I want to pass the selected trainer_id value to the trainer_view method. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) I would recommend using jQuery and AJAX to accomplish your goal, this is how I would try to do it:

First, I would drop the `<%= link_to_remote %>` under the `collection_select` so it would look like this:

```
<%= collection_select("event", "trainer_id", @trainers , :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Select a Trainer'}) %>
<div id="trainerCalendar"></div>
```

Then, put this JavaScript in your application.js, when the DOM is ready:

```
$('#trainer_id').live('change', function() {
  $('#trainerCalendar').html.empty;
  $.ajax({ url: '/trainer_view/',
    data: 'id=' + this.value,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#trainerCalendar').html(data);
    }
  })
});
```

You can have your controller respond with a partial of the calendar.

Hope this helps!